# Why does "like the days you went out Egypt I'll show him wonders" change subjects?

Tags: messiah, micah

In [Michah 7:15](https://www.sefaria.org/Micah.7.15?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) it says "Like the days you went out of Egypt I'll show him wonders", why does the verse start off in the second person with "... The days **you** went out" and finish in the third person (either singular or plural) "I'll show **him** {or them} wonders", why didn't it say "I'll show **you** wonders"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ibn Ezra sees the two groups to be different:
כימי צאתך - והטעם: כימי צאת אבותיך מארץ מצרים

"like the days of your fathers' leaving Egypt"

vs

"הטעם עמי, כאשר הזכיר עמך."

Speaking of the nation as a singular (as it is introduced in the previous verse, "רְעֵ֧ה עַמְּךָ֣").

The Malbim actually sees the second half as a statement of the future redemption of a collective (singular) nation "אראנו נפלאות לעתיד לבוא".